# Method is returning NaN even though the calculation is correct

Tags: java, class, methods

When I call the methods (in another class) that should return the calculated angles angleA, angleB, angleC, I get the result NaN.  I have triple checked all my calculations so there has to be something in how I've set up the program.  What have I made wrong??

```
/* Write a Java program enabled to compute and show the following properties of a given triangle :
    The individual length of all sides
    The angles at all corners
    The perimeter
    The area

    */

   public class Triangle
   {
    private double x1, x2, x3, y1, y2, y3;
    double sideA, sideB, sideC;
    private double angleA, angleB, angleC;
    double longestSide, shortSide1, shortSide2;
    private double perimeter, halfPerimeter, triangleArea;
    private String stringLongestSide;

    public Triangle(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2, double x3, double y3)
    {
        this.x1 = x1;
       this.y1 = y1;
       this.x2 = x2;
       this.y2 = y2;
       this.x3 = x3;
       this.y3 = y3;
    }

    public double getSideA()
    {
    return (Math.sqrt(Math.pow((x3-x2),2)+Math.pow((y3-y2),2)));
    }

    public double getSideB()
    {
    return (Math.sqrt(Math.pow((x3-x1),2)+Math.pow((y3-y1),2)));
    }

    public double getSideC()
    {
    return (Math.sqrt(Math.pow((x2-x1),2)+ Math.pow((y2-y1),2)));
    }



        //Begin by using the cosine rule to find the largest angle
    public double getAngleA()
    {
            //which side is the longest?

        longestSide = sideA;
        shortSide1 = sideB;
        shortSide2 = sideC;

        if (longestSide < sideC)
        {
            longestSide = sideC;
            shortSide1 = sideA;
            shortSide2 = sideB;             
        }
            else
            if (longestSide < sideB)
            {
            longestSide = sideB;
            shortSide1 = sideA;
            shortSide2 = sideC;
            }

    return (Math.acos((Math.pow(shortSide1,2)+Math.pow(shortSide2,2)-Math.pow(longestSide,2))/(2*shortSide1*shortSide2)))*180/Math.PI;
    }

        //Use the sine rule to find one of the remaining angles 
    public double getAngleB()
    {
    return ((Math.asin((shortSide1*Math.sin((angleA*Math.PI/180))/longestSide)))*180/Math.PI);
    }   

        //Use the 'sum of internal angles' rule to find the third angle
    public double getAngleC()
    {
    return (180 - (angleA + angleB));
    }


    //Calculating the perimeter
    public double getPerimeter()
    {
    return (sideA + sideB + sideC);
    }

//Calculating the area of the triangle
    public double getArea()
    {
    halfPerimeter = perimeter/2;
    return (Math.sqrt(halfPerimeter*(halfPerimeter-sideA) * (halfPerimeter-sideB) * (halfPerimeter-sideC)));
    }

    }
```

The class calling the methods:

```
/* ShellApplication
    Rakel Bára Þorvaldsdóttir
*/
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class Interaction
{
    public static void main(String [] args)  //required
    {
    //write your code here
    double x1, x2, x3, y1, y2, y3;
    double sideA, sideB, sideC;
    double angleA, angleB, angleC;
    double perimeter, area;

    DecimalFormat coordinates = new DecimalFormat ("#");
    DecimalFormat calculations = new DecimalFormat ("#.##");

    System.out.println("Welcome!");
    System.out.println("Please enter the coordinates of your triangle, the x-coordinate first each time and then the y-coordinate.\n\t------------------------\n");

    String garbage;

    Scanner scan = new Scanner( System.in );

    System.out.print( "Enter the x-coordinate for the first point, and then press Enter: ");
    while (! scan.hasNextInt())
    {
        garbage = scan.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Please enter an integer.");
    } 
        x1 = scan.nextDouble( );

    System.out.print( "Enter the y-coordinate for the first point, and then press Enter: ");
    while (! scan.hasNextInt())  //creating a while loop to ensure only integer numbers are accepted
    {
        garbage = scan.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Please enter an integer.");
    }
       y1 = scan.nextDouble( );

    System.out.print( "Thanks for entering the first point. Now on to the next! \n\t------------------------\n");

    System.out.print( "Enter the x-coordinate for the second point, and then press Enter: ");
    while (! scan.hasNextInt())
    {
        garbage = scan.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Please enter an integer.");
    }
      x2 = scan.nextDouble( );

    System.out.print( "Enter the y-coordinate for the second point, and then press Enter: ");
    while (! scan.hasNextInt())
    {
        garbage = scan.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Please enter an integer.");
    }
      y2 = scan.nextDouble( );

    System.out.print( "Thanks for entering the second point. Just one more left! \n\t------------------------\n");

    System.out.print( "Enter the x-coordinate for the third point, and then press Enter: ");
    while (! scan.hasNextInt())
    {
        garbage = scan.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Please enter an integer.");
    }
      x3 = scan.nextDouble( );

    System.out.print( "Enter the y-coordinate for the third point, and then press Enter: ");
    while (! scan.hasNextInt())
    {
        garbage = scan.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Please enter an integer.");
    }
      y3 = scan.nextDouble( );

    System.out.println( "You did it!  Your triangle has the following coordinates: ");
    System.out.println( "Point A: ("+coordinates.format(x1) +" , " +coordinates.format(y1) +")" + " , Point B: ("+coordinates.format(x2) +" , " +coordinates.format(y2) +")" +  " , Point C: ("+coordinates.format(x3) +" , " +coordinates.format(y3) +")");

    Triangle userTriangle = new Triangle(x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3);   

     sideA = userTriangle.getSideA();
     sideB = userTriangle.getSideB();
     sideC = userTriangle.getSideC();

     angleA = userTriangle.getAngleA();
     angleB = userTriangle.getAngleB();
     angleC = userTriangle.getAngleC();

     perimeter = userTriangle.getPerimeter();
     area = userTriangle.getArea();

     System.out.println( "-----------------");
     System.out.println( "SideA is: " +calculations.format(sideA));
     System.out.println( "SideB is: " +calculations.format(sideB));
     System.out.println( "SideC is: " +calculations.format(sideC));
     System.out.println( "-----------------");

     System.out.println( "AngleA is: " +angleA);
     System.out.println( "AngleB is: " +angleB);
     System.out.println( "AngleC is: " +angleC);
     System.out.println( "-----------------");

     System.out.println( "Perimeter is: " +perimeter);
     System.out.println( "Area is: " +area);


    }
}
```

And the result is:

---

SideA is: 14,32
SideB is: 5,83

### SideC is: 11,18

AngleA is: NaN
AngleB is: NaN

### AngleC is: 180.0

Perimeter is: 0.0
Area is: 0.0

Comment: And which method exactly return NaN?

Comment: And what was was your input?

Comment: x1 = 1, y1 = 44, x2 = 3, y2 = 55, x3 = 6, y3 = 41

Comment: The way your getters update and depend on instance fields makes my head hurt.

Comment: You don't initialise `sideA` - `sideC` in `Triangle`, so they are `0` when you use them.

Comment: The `sideA` local variable in `main` and the `Triangle.sideA` field are different things.

Comment: Do you mean in the two different classes?  If so, I am aware of that.  But if you mean sideA and Triangle.sideA in class Triangle, then I have to admit I am confused.

Answer (score 3):

Some of your variables are not being initialised with proper values before you are using them.  sideA, sideB and sideC for example, are all 0.0 in your getAngleA() method.

If you use their default values (which obviously is 0.0 for class variables : doubles) and then try to divide by that, the result will be NaN (well Infinity really, but if you try to calculate using infinity you get NaN as the result).

When you call getAngleA() from the call:

```
angleA = userTriangle.getAngleA();
```

Print out the following method variables, and they are all 0.0

Your variables as set in the method getAngleA():

```
longestSide = sideA;
shortSide1 = sideB;
shortSide2 = sideC;
```

Printout of their values immediately after they are set:

```
System.out.println("longestSide = " + longestSide);
System.out.println("shortSide1 = " + shortSide1);
System.out.println("shortSide2 = " + shortSide2);
```

This is what is printed out:
    longestSide = 0.0
    shortSide1 = 0.0
    shortSide2 = 0.0

So they aren't being set with values other than 0.0.

Comment: Hah - yes it appeared in between me starting typing my answer, and hitting "post"..  Ya gotta be quick on here don't you!?  ;-)

Comment: So that would appear to be the problem - you need to provide values for any variables you are using to divide by, or they are 0.0 by default which returns a Nan for doubles or floats.

Comment: But I thought my calculations passed the values into my variables?  Sorry I'm new at this :-/

Comment: Just having a quick play with it.

When you call getAngleA() from the call: 

angleA = userTriangle.getAngleA();

Print out the following method variables, and they are all 0.
Your variables as set in the method:
longestSide = sideA;
shortSide1 = sideB;
shortSide2 = sideC;
Printout of their values:
System.out.println("longestSide = " + longestSide);
System.out.println("shortSide1 = " + shortSide1);
System.out.println("shortSide2 = " + shortSide2);     
longestSide = 0.0     
shortSide1 = 0.0     
shortSide2 = 0.0    
So they aren't being set.

Comment: I see what you mean, so the calculations from my methods don't get "forwarded" to my next method.  hmmmm...how the heck do I fix that?

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help!!

Comment: Implementing the methods Sura has put below should do the trick, although a getter method really shouldn't be doing any setting, so you are better to add some setter methods too with the code to set the values, and then the getter methods just return those values. That would be the correctly encapsulated way to do it, and if you are doing this for a project/homework/etc, you would likely lose marks for setting values in a getter method.

Answer (score 2):

This is the change you have to do in Trangle class. in each Side getting method instead of returning value you have to first assing values to sideA,sideB,sideC and then return

```
public double getSideA()
 {
  sideA = (Math.sqrt(Math.pow((x3-x2),2)+Math.pow((y3-y2),2)));
  return sideA;
}

 public double getSideB()
{
sideB =  (Math.sqrt(Math.pow((x3-x1),2)+Math.pow((y3-y1),2)));
 return sideB;
}

 public double getSideC()
 {
 sideC = (Math.sqrt(Math.pow((x2-x1),2)+ Math.pow((y2-y1),2)));
 return sideC;
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

To correctly encapsulate your fields, you need to set all your class variables to private access, and use getters and setters to set and get the values.

To expand on Sura's answer therefore, you would add these methods to your Triangle class, and set your sideA, sideB and sideC (as well as all your other class variables) to private

e.g.

```
public double getSideA()
{
  return sideA;
}

public double getSideB()
{
  return sideB;
}

public double getSideC()
{
  return sideC;
}

public void setSideA()
{
  sideA = (Math.sqrt(Math.pow((x3-x2),2)+Math.pow((y3-y2),2)));
}

public void setSideB()
{
  sideB =  (Math.sqrt(Math.pow((x3-x1),2)+Math.pow((y3-y1),2)));
}

public void setSideC()
{
  sideC = (Math.sqrt(Math.pow((x2-x1),2)+ Math.pow((y2-y1),2)));
}
```

Having said that - I'm guessing that in your Triangle case you don't want to allow people to update your side measurements without altering your initial input values (your x, y, z variables), in which case I would omit the setters completely and add Sura's 3 side-setting lines instead to the bottom of your constructor, so they are set upon initialisation of the object.

```
sideA = (Math.sqrt(Math.pow((x3-x2),2)+Math.pow((y3-y2),2))); 
sideB = (Math.sqrt(Math.pow((x3-x1),2)+Math.pow((y3-y1),2)));  
sideC = (Math.sqrt(Math.pow((x2-x1),2)+ Math.pow((y2-y1),2)));
```

If you want people to then be able to change the dimensions of your triangle, I would suggest just a single updateTriangle() method, which runs your input menu again for the new values, and once more includes these 3 lines at the bottom to update your sides to the new values.